# python selenium webscraping i can not write "ö"

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

Hello guys I am trying web **scraping** with selenium but I cannot write stuff like "ö"

```py
    def loop():
        actualLetter = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="actualLetter"]').text
        text_done = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="textInput"]')
        print(actualLetter)
        ''''
        for x in range(len(letter)):
            for y in letter[x]:
                keyboard.press(y)
                keyboard.release(y)
        '''
        if actualLetter == "Ö":
            text_done.send_keys(chr(214))
        elif actualLetter == "ö":
            text_done.send_keys('\u00F6')
        else:
            text_done.send_keys(actualLetter)
        time.sleep(speed)
        loop()

    loop()
```

I tried  so many stuff like replacing ö with codes like chr or '\u00F6'

Comment: where in the code are you 'writing "ö"'?  the character "ö" should be identifiable as you have written it, no need to use keycodes. We might need a more reproducible example in the question..

Comment: So its like i get actualLetter from the website and send it as a key press. It is working by normal characters like a or b but not by ö

Comment: What is the error message you receive? Or what does "cannot write" mean?

Comment: no error but it just doesnt write ö